# Issue with Umbraco Service - "Nullable object must have value"

Tags: service, nodes, umbraco, nullable

We're implementing different **Umbraco service** using **ApplicationContext** to pull data from Umbraco backend. It always give null in return or gives exception of "Nullable object must have value" while calling the service method itself.
This is might because of NULL in **nodeUser** column in **umbracoNode** table. If I update 0 in Database, my service runs fine. But it again sets **nodeUser** to NULL if I perform save in umbraco backend.

Here is my code :

```
var contentService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;

var contentTypeService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentTypeService;

var contentType = contentTypeService.GetContentType("blog");

var contents = contentService.GetContentOfContentType(contentType.Id);
```

[image: Screenshot of Content]

Can anyone help me to get out of this?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of the code that's throwing/returning the error?  Those 4 lines alone aren't enough to get any context on the problem, and aren't likely to be the source of your problem.  The `UserId` field can be null by design, so if you're accessing it and assuming it's not null this may be causing your problem.

Comment: var contentType = contentTypeService.GetContentType("blog");
This is the line throwing/returning error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the version of UmbracoCms.Core to the latest resolved the problem.